# Google Apps Marketplace app - how to add scopes for supporting app

Tags: google-app-engine, manifest, scopes, google-apps-marketplace

We have two appengine apps.  One is a service app that provides data for the other, which is customer-facing.  We are putting the customer-facing app into Google Marketplace as an installable app. We would like to include scopes in the application manifest for accessing the Provisioning API.  However, it is the service app that needs this access.

Is it possible to specify scopes in the manifest that give access to another application?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same consumer key/secret you got from the marketplace (customer facing) app in the "service app".

Comment: The service app will ultimately serve multiple customer facing apps.  I will test out having the marketplace app pass its key/secret to the service app.  Thank you!

Comment: each customer facing app can identify itself to the service app and the service app can select the correct credentials based on that information... should work.

Comment: In case you're still working on the app, the way specify scopes has changed with the new Google Apps Marketplace experience. See https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/preparing